# How to import prebuild multi-dll shared library gracefully with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on cmake to import a prebuild shared libary which has one lib file and multi dll files.

The file tree is like below:

```
bin/
bin/foo1.dll
bin/foo2.dll
bin/foo3.dll
include/
include/foo.hxx
lib/
lib/foo.lib
```

Here is what i am doing:

```
# --- foo1 ---
add_library(foo::foo1 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
    foo::foo1
    PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/foo.lib
    IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/foo1.dll
)

# --- foo2 ---
add_library(foo::foo2 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
    foo::foo2
    PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/foo.lib
    IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/foo2.dll
)

...

add_library(foo::foo INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET foo::foo PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES
    foo::foo1
    foo::foo2
    foo::foo3
    foo::foo4
)
```

But i think it's boilerplate, is there any better idea?

I checked some relevant stackoverflow answer, but i still have no valid clue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can make a CMake macro or function to eliminate all the duplicate work.

Comment: @drescherjm thx for the opinion, it sound a practical way.

Comment: The alternative would be using `foreach(LIB IN ITEMS foo1 foo2 foo3) ... endforeach()`. Btw: I'd recommend using `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` or `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` depending on your needs, since this doesn't rely on the location of a `project()` command...